# Fresh prestashop 1.7 install curl timeout

Tags: prestashop-1.7, php-curl

I am trying to install Prestashop on my local machine

Using ubuntu 18.04, php 7.2, mysql 5.6, apache 2.4

I have cloned from their github repo, checkouted to branch 1.7.6.x, installed composer dependencies and made a symbolic link to the code directory from my `/var/www/html` (didn't want to bother creating a vhost)

Opened chromium to `http://127.0.0.1/prestashop/install-dev/index.php`

Proceeded with all steps, with correct mysql settings, directory permission settings, left the language to English (English)

But during the Store Installation step, when "Installing addons modules", it fails with a curl error like this:

```
file_get_contents_curl failed to download http://i18n.prestashop.com/translations/1.7.6.7/en-US/en-US.zip : (error code 28) Operation timed out after 5001 milliseconds with 221832 out of 516048 bytes received
```

I also have the following info in the Request tab of my inspector:

- It's calling `http://127.0.0.1/prestashop/install-dev/index.php?installModulesAddons=true&_=1596718771175` with status_code 200
- I have the following as response body in there:

```
{
    "success":false,
    "message":"file_get_contents_curl failed to download http:\/\/i18n.prestashop.com\/translations\/1.7.6.7\/en-US\/en-US.zip : (error code 28) Operation timed out after 5001 milliseconds with 221832 out of 516048 bytes received"
}
```

I checked the file in `install-dev/controllers/http/process.php` but the code that I think is called just looks like this:

```php
    /**
     * PROCESS : installModulesAddons
     * Install modules from addons
     */
    public function processInstallAddonsModules()
    {
        $this->initializeContext();
        if (($module = Tools::getValue('module')) && $id_module = Tools::getValue('id_module')) {
            $result = $this->model_install->installModulesAddons(array('name' => $module, 'id_module' => $id_module));
        } else {
            $result = $this->model_install->installModulesAddons();
        }
        if (!$result || $this->model_install->getErrors()) {
            $this->ajaxJsonAnswer(false, $this->model_install->getErrors());
        }
        $this->session->process_validated = array_merge($this->session->process_validated, array('installModulesAddons' => true));
        $this->ajaxJsonAnswer(true);
    }
```

I suspect my faulty internet is to blame, but is there a workaround to increase the curl timeout?

Answer (score -1):

Comment the code lines like this:

[image]

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow. Please do not post screenshots of code, as it is impossible to copy from it and there's no garauntees that image will be available long enough for the future users.

Use code snippets inside stackoverflow answer instead. More info [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)